# Get the name of a connected screen Swift

Tags: swift, macos, display

Does anyone know of a way to get the screen name, or model name/number from a display that is connected to the system?  I've been looking around for quite some time to see if there is a way to do this.  The only method I've seen anyone post only works with a deprecated API (`CGDisplayIOServicePort`), (and there's not replacement listed for that API), so that isn't really an option.

Basically, I am wanting to give the user a list of connected screens to display the output of the app, and I feel like giving them a list of names of the displays would be much more elegant and nicer than whatever the ID is that is returned from `NSScreen` or `CGGetActiveDisplayList`, etc.  It has to possible, when you go to the display preferences in OS X it gives you the names of the displays there.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the names of connected screens directly from IOReg

```
func screenNames() -> [String] {

  var names = [String]()
  var object : io_object_t
  var serialPortIterator = io_iterator_t()
  let matching = IOServiceMatching("IODisplayConnect")

  let kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault,
                                                matching,
                                                &serialPortIterator)
  if KERN_SUCCESS == kernResult && serialPortIterator != 0 {
    repeat {
      object = IOIteratorNext(serialPortIterator)
      let info = IODisplayCreateInfoDictionary(object, UInt32(kIODisplayOnlyPreferredName)).takeRetainedValue() as NSDictionary as! [String:AnyObject]
      if let productName = info["DisplayProductName"] as? [String:String],
         let firstKey = Array(productName.keys).first {
            names.append(productName[firstKey]!)
      }

    } while object != 0
  }
  IOObjectRelease(serialPortIterator)
  return names
}

let names = screenNames()
```

Comment: That's awesome!  Thank you, it works perfectly.  I looked for days for something that would do this, maybe I just wasn't looking for the right things.

Comment: You're welcome. Probably you was looking only in the `Quartz Display Services` but there is no API anyway to get the product name of a display

Comment: That is where I was looking, there and the `NSScreen` class.  I am going to try to do a lot of reading on all the APIs in your code to hopefully understand it all a bit better.

Comment: It's just standard [C API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Finding_Devices/AH_Finding_Devices.html) to parse IORegistry

Answer (score 8):

macOS 10.15 Catalina introduced a new property [`localizedName`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/3228043-localizedname) for getting the external display name:

```
NSScreen.screens.forEach {
    print($0.localizedName)
}
```

Comment: This is good to have since I use a venues TV screen(s) as external displays and it will be nice to get their screen name and save it so whenever I connect my laptop to their display I can use the saved screen name to automatically throw up a customized view for that venue.